# iPad CSS breaks on orientation change while keyboard is active while using FullPage.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, viewport, fullpage.js

This could be a meta viewport issue or a css issue, but I was able to replicate a similar issue with the default fullPage.js code (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). If you add an input field to a slide, open the keyboard in landscape, then change the orientation to portrait, the css breaks.

Result is you will see a black space on the side if you rotate from Landscape to Portrait, and at the bottom (once you hide the keyboard) if you rotate from portrait to landscape.

I have not altered the css to the fullpage framework, so I am unsure on where the problem stems, but if you have any ideas for work around, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it so that on the event of the iPad being rotated the program focuses on a read-only input box like:

```
<input type="text" id="invis" name="someInput" readonly="readonly" />
```

which, is, as the ID suggests, invisible (use css).  This will minimize the keyboard, and stop the webpage from breaking.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as intended. This is what I have for what you suggested: $(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {$("#invis").focus();});

Comment: What's the thing that isn't working as intended?  Are you still getting the same problem?  If so, is it because it is actually minimizing the keyboard after the orientation change?

Comment: So the focus on the hidden field does minimize the keyboard, but does not remove the black. Which makes me think it has to do with the viewport... I have tried to hack away at the CSS and reBuild fullPage.js on orientation change, but no luck. this is my current viewport: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>

Comment: Oh, well then I'm at a loss then, I don't know too much about view port issues.  Sorry I couldn't help.